# Motorcycle clutch

Tags: honda, motorcycle, transmission, clutch

Honda xl350 1974
Clutch not working bike won't go into neutral, I can shift it (bike not running obviously)

Riding home bike it slowed down, engine then stalled, costed about 20ft then the back wheel locked up. Bike was stuck in a gear tried to find neutral but couldn't. Pulled clutch in to push the bike but couldn't it acts like it's still in gear. Rocked it back a forth to see of it would free it up but nothing I can shift all the gears. Just not neutral and the clutch don't work. Please help tnx

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: When you squeeze the clutch does the action feel different from normal, like easier or harder to pull?

Comment: Can you down shift into first while moving the bike back and forth until you're into first gear, then up shift to neutral? This should at least give you indications the transmission is intact to separate a clutch from transmission problem.

Comment: Nope feels fine took it apart its all moving just no first gear or neutral either... shift 2345 just fine

Comment: I think you may have two problems; transmission unable to shift to neutral/1st and clutch.  Unfortunately, a tear down is needed. Clutches do not interfere with gear shifts with engine off when moving the bike forward or back a little to allow shifts.

Comment: Thanks know that already makes no difference rocking back and forth its broken inside I have to find the special tools and time to take it apart. Clutch is perfect like I said thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a snapped clutch cable. This is assuming that your unit is not a hydraulic clutch.